# 18.04 LTS does not recognize dual monitors correctly?

Tags: multiple-monitors, 18.04, hdmi, amd-graphics

Hardware:
Integrated Graphics: AMD Trinity Radeo HD 7660D; Note to readers, I do have the latest drivers for the AMD graphics system: "If you're running Ubuntu 18.04, you already have the open source AMD drivers installed. They're integrated into Mesa and the Linux kernel."
PC Monitor1: Samsung 2268W; digital port
PC Monitor2: GPX TV/Monitor using HDMI port or Vizio TV/Monitor using HDMI

First monitor is the main computer monitor. With 14.xx through 17.xx there were work arounds I could use, not so with 18.04. There is only one monitor shown in Settings ever. Doesn't matter how I set up the BIOS, or when I plug in the HDMI, the Samsung goes black, and the picture switches to the 2nd monitor. That's not how all the other Ubuntu versions worked and although there were problems with dual monitors there too, at least I had both working.

This version doesn't seem to recognize what it previously could recognize...that I have two monitors and want to run them both at the same time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as often happens, as soon as I posted this question, I found the solution. My main monitor was plugged into the computers Digital DVI port, and apparently, this ASUS mobo can only run SVGA and HDMI at the same time but cannot run DVI and HDMI. My monitor is dual input so switching it to SVGA restored Ubuntu's Dual monitor settings.

So, problem solved...